# How to declare a global variable which calls an object in C++?

Tags: c++, qt

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder;
    QAudioEncoderSettings audioSettings;
    audioSettings.setCodec("audio/amr");
    audioSettings.setQuality(QMultimedia::HighQuality);

    audioRecorder->setEncodingSettings(audioSettings);

    audioRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile("test.amr"));
    audioRecorder->record();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
 //How to use audioRecorder variable???
}
```

I want to use the audioRecorder variable into the last method of my code. because when I declare `audioRecorder = new QAudioRecorder;`, the variable audio recorder is only accessible into the method on_pushButton_clicked(), so I want to make this variable usable into the method n_pushButton_2_clicked(). How to do it ?

Comment: If `audioRecorder` is a member of MainWindow, then it is accessible in all of its methods.

Comment: You need to declare it as a member variable in the class.

Comment: Ok, so what I need to write into my mainwindow.h class ? Into the private bloc....

Comment: That should be covered in any C++ tutorial, which one are you learning from? Seriously, your question shows that you didn't spend a single minute trying things or doing research, a behaviour that's generally frowned upon here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like some person said in the comments, you need to have your QAudioRecorder object declared as a member of your MainWindow class.

So basically you need something like this :

```
QAudioRecorder* audioRecorder;//This could also be a shared_ptr
```

Then, your audioRecorder object is created in your on_pushButton_clicked() function.

You can now use it in on_pushButton_2_clicked() function.

However, this is quite unsafe, for example, if you did not create the audioRecorder before calling on_pushButton_2_clicked(), audioRecorder is not going to point to a valid object and this will most certainly crash your project.

So before using it in on_pushButton_2_clicked(), verify if its valid:

```
if(audioRecorder)
{
// You can use audioRecorder safely here
}
```

Comment: @Thomas It really depends on what you want to do. If it's something you do not want constantly in memory, than a pointer is what you need, you can allocate/deallocate the object at will. Otherwise, yeah, the object could be a member var.

Comment: Setting up audio takes time. If you want short delays then  the devices should be created beforehand.

Comment: @Thomas I was talking in a generic sense. I'm not saying in this specific case, as I don't know how QAudioRecorder is implemented.

Comment: When value based, it will go away when its owner gets destroyed. Using raw pointers for ownership is dangerous. Using shared pointer when you don't share is also wrong. Objects should usually have an owner. If that owner wants so create and destroy instances, a `unique_ptr` is a the preferred smart pointer.

Comment: Yep, you are right. Again, I was talking in a generic sense, since I don't know how QAudioRecorder is implemented, how it will be shared (if it will or not, etc).

All the stuff you mention is valid and I agree, I just think it eludes the scope of the question...

Anyway, it's good of you to point it out.